# What pre-requistes do i need

Tags: c#, installation

I have created a windows desktop c# vs2010 application.

I have created an installer.

On all pcs so far it installs OK.

On a new build I get this:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

I have installed .Net 4 Client Profile

What else do I need to prompt the user to install for my app to work?

Comment: Time ago I have the same problem. I've solved it simply adding to the exe folder the System.Web DLL

Comment: AFAIK, `System.Web` is for ASP.NET web applications, and not for desktop apps. Anyway, it's part of the full .NET install.

Comment: HI, to both of you. I am using web services. Thanks both for the info :

Comment: @kol the System.web DLL it's also available for Desktop framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1, please ensure to unable your anti-virus and some security software, perhaps, to close your firewall, some customers discover some issues are caused by firewall.

This’s a similar thread like your, you could refer to the following link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/7f956744-95ff-421e-8da2-d2f0a42b881c

Step 2, you should download .NET Framework 4 from the following link (Microsoft).

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7

Step 3, if it have some issues during installing framework, you could download ‘Collect.exe’, which could help you to collect information during installing .NET Framework 4

Step 4, try to clean your "%temp%" folder (Start Menu >> Run >> Type "%temp%")

Step 5, reinstall .NET Framework 4

It will create a file named %temp%\vslogs.cab on your system.

More information about how to use ‘Collect’, you could refer to the following link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/11/21/6458047.aspx

If it has none issues during installing framework, you could re-run your program in previous issue’s machine, and try it again.

Hope this helps you! If you have any doubts and concerns, please feel free to let me know. We are going to continue to follow-up.

Best Regards

Comment: WOW! what a great answer. I will go through these steps soon (been called in for dinner) and feedback. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need the full .NET 4 install, not the Client Profile. The Client Profile does not include System.Web.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. So, I do not need to the client profile at all? Just the full install (I know dumb question :)).  Also, should I include it my own set up or should I let the User be prompted to download it? Thanks

Comment: {I got to wait 6 minutes before accepting your answer for some reason.  But I will)

Comment: Right - you need the full .NET, which is a superset of the Client Profile. It's up to you if you want to ask the user to download it or include it. The tradeoff is that your installer will be bloated if you include it, but it will save the user from having to download a large .NET installer.